# Is it possible to access the other members of an interface type?

Tags: c#

I'm curious if this is possible, and if not, what are the reasons behind it if any, and how would one handle this programming scenario?

Let's say i have this interface:

```
public interface IBook
{
    void BookClient();
    void CancelClient();
}
```

and i have this class that implements the above interface:

```
public class Photographer : IBook
{
     public void BookClient()
     {
        // do something
     }

     public void CancelClient()
     {
        // do something
     }

     // non-interface methods
     public void SaveClients()
     {
        // do something
     }

     public void DeleteClients()
     {
        // do something
     }
}
```

Now if I assign this class to an interface type somewhere in my code such as:

```
IBook photo;
photo = new Photographer();
```

Is it possible to do this:

```
// non-interface member from the Photographer class
photo.SaveClients();
```

Can someone straighten me out on this issue and perhaps point me in the right direction regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: Using reflection, sure, or if you know that `photo` is a `Photographer` you can cast it.

Comment: SaveClients is method from Photographer not IBook, if you do `Photographer photo = new Photografer` you can access `photo.SaveClients()`

Comment: Keep in mind that an interface is a contract; it says, 'I guarantee that these methods will be available.'  Implementors of the interface can provide additional methods, but they are not available unless you re-cast the object to a type that defines those methods (as given in the answer from @MarcinJuraszek below)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you have to cast your `photo` into `Photographer` first:

```
// non-interface member from the Photographer class
((Photographer)photo).SaveClients();
```

It's not possible with just `photo.SaveClients()` syntax, because you can easily create another class:

```
class TestClass : IBook
{
    public void BookClient()
    {
       // do something
    }
     public void CancelClient()
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
IBook photo;
photo = new Photographer();
photo = new TestClass();

// what should happen here?
photo.SaveClients();
```

So as long as you use the variable as an interface implementation, you can only access member declared in that interface. However, the object is still a class instance, so you can use other class members, but you have to explicitly cast to that type first.

Answer (score 2):

Interface types can only reference interface members. You're attempting to invoke a member of the class which is not part of the interface.

You can try (can't test right now):

```
IBook photo;
photo = new Photographer();

(photo as Photographer).SaveClients();
// or
((Photographer)photo).SaveClients();
```

Comment: The approach with `as` is a bad idea. It will fail with a non-descriptive `NullReferenceException` if `photo` is not a `Photographer`.

Comment: ...Whereas the direct cast will fail with an `InvalidCastException` which is much more clear and to the point. That's what you're meaning, right, @DanielHilgarth? ;)

Comment: I think the point is that you should never try to dereference an expression that could be null...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, using reflection. Also you can cast to `Photographer` and then call `SaveClients()`.

In my opinion a good solution is defining each group of actions you need to call in an interface, then, cast to that interface, and call the method you need:

```
public interface IBook
{
    void BookClient();
    void CancelClient();
}

public interface IClient
{
    void SaveClients();
}
```

And then use as:

```
IBook photo = new Photographer();
// now cast photo object as a IClient
IClient client = photo as IClient;
if (client != null)
{
    client.SaveClients();
}
```